# Adding my button to google sites

Tags: html, button, sites

I click edit page on my google site and then add html box where i add this code

```
<button type="button" onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com','_blank','resizable=yes')" >Click to open Google</button>
```

But for some reason it doesn't work, although i tested it on some html editors and it worked.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can also try this

```
<a href="www.google.com" targer="_blank"><input type="button" value="Click to open Google" /></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be some kind of security feature, the code is correct, you can see it [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/DhAfj/1/). But [Here](http://codepen.io/joe/pen/IqCvf) it doesn't work too.

You can try to use a link:

```
<a href="www.google.com" target="_blank">Click to open Google</a>
```

Ps.: It's good to close all tags (`</button>` after button's text):

```
<button type="button" onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com','_blank','resizable=yes')" >Click to open Google</button>
```